# Java LDAP search cant seem to handle spaces

Tags: java, ldap

When calling javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext's search() method, passing in the DN...

```
OU=User Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AceCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AceCloud,DC=local
```

The error is outputted is `Authentication failed. failed to authenticate user:[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0315270B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0.`

```
LdapName baseDN = new LdapName(baseDN
NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(baseDN, "("+ identity.getBindAttribute() + "=" + acctname + ")", sc);
```

The problem occurs due to the space in `User Structure`. When I placed the users in another OU that doesn't contain a space, I am able to authenticate fine. I’ve tried all of the following:

```
OU=User\ Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User\20Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User\\20Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User%Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User\ Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User\\ Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
OU=User\\\\ Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local
```

None works. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, there should not be any spaces after the colon, distinguished names do not contain them. Try like that, see if it works - I have personally never had problems with spaces in DNs. If it fails, try to replace spaces with `%20`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention we also tried OU=User%20Structure, OU=Acecity(LTO), OU=AcecityCloud,OU=Hosting, DC=AcecityCloud,DC=local but it doesn't work either

Comment: Okay, but try without spaces after colons...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by spaces after colon. I don't see a colon there. The DN works with an OU that does not contain a space. e.g. OU=Users. I think the problem arises because the LdapName calls out to Rfc2253Parser. See: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/naming/ldap/Rfc2253Parser.java.html. In line 118, it calls Rdn.unescapeValue(value)). If I were to present an escaped Rdn, what would be the ramifications?

Answer (score 1):

Spaces can cause issues with openldap if they are not escaped properly.

```
'OU="User Structure",OU=Acecity(LTO),OU=AceCloud,OU=Hosting,DC=AceCloud,DC=local'
```

To avoid issues, enclose the entire BINDDN with single quotes, and enclose the Common Name (CN), Organizational Unit (OU) or Domain Component (DC) containing a space character with double quotes.